# Need help designing a hairdryer

Tags: diodes, motor, dc-motor, appliances, ac-motor

I'm designing a hairdryer as project for a university class, but I'm having trouble regarding the choice of the motor. I need it to have two possible speeds. My first idea was to use an AC motor and a diode as in the schematic below, when the current flows through the diode, half of the AC wave gets cut, so the motor runs at half speed. My first question is: Will it work?

I also tried to use a DC motor instead with a rectifier bridge, but using the aforementioned diode to cut the wave in half doesn't seem to change to voltage on the motor very much, how can I make it work with I choose to use a DC motor?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please don't do this.  It's a really terrible idea for a project, all tied up in safety and thermal concerns and challenging to physically fabricate.  Maybe do a temperature controlled air source for soldering preheat if you really want to play with heating coils and fans.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sadly I have no choice, but I'm aware of the danger and safety precautions and only have to come up with the schematic.

Comment: A hairdryer uses to have a simple circuit... the basic circuit is well stablished at, maybe, 30 or 40 years. You can open a hairdryer to see what there is inside. There is a lot of schematics on the web, just Google for "hair dryer schematic"

Comment: What's the purpose of the 10 ohm resistors?

Comment: @mguima - Hairdryers are like that as well. The motor is driven from a tap on the heating element through a rectifier. The tap is changed to change the speed.

Comment: @KevinWhite I deleted the comment saying that hairdryers _always_ have the heating element and motor wired in parallel, trusting in what you said about the tap in the heating element. But, in my limited experience, there is also **a lot of hairdryers with this configuration** [shematic](http://doczz.com.br/doc/185506/esquema-el%C3%A9trico-secador-de-cabelo-taiff---tany), all of them use AC motors, and there is no rectifier. The only diode in the circuit is used to permit half-wave operation. I've personally opened several hairdryers like that.

Comment: @KevinWhite This exact kind of hairdryer circuit, with a pair of three-pole switches is a classic: 1) Low fan, no heat; 2) High fan, no heat; 3) Low fan, low heat; 4) High fan, low heat; 5) High fan, high heat. (I'm in doubt if there is a 6) low fan, high heat). The operation of the switches to achieve those modes is not linear, is somewhat ilogical, but the user gets acquainted with it.

Comment: @KevinWhite If the motor is feed through a tap in the heating element, there would be no way of using the hairdryer only as a fan. Maybe some **very cheap** devices are like that - just like those cheap hot air guns.

Comment: @mguima - See Sphero's answer.

Comment: @KevinWhite I saw his answer. He posted a circuit of hairdryer, one of the cheapest, that hairdryer is like the hot air gun. The kind of hairdryer that I described is a better, intermediary model - although it is not a "super-high-end" as the Dyson hairdryer that Sphero told about. The ones that I'm talking about cost about $100 USD.

Comment: @mguima, thanks for your answer. The schematic you linked is exactly what I've been looking for ,I just don't get why the diode is wired between the switches. I believe that the circuit I proposed works in a similar way, doesn't it ? Will it do the same job ?

Comment: @gabs136 That schematic was provided by the manufacturer, I'm sorry that the schematic was not canonically drawed. The key to understanding this circuit is understanding how those switches work. The switches have three positions: (A) all pins unconnected; (B) pin 1 connected to pin 2; (C) all three pins interconnected. The diode is there for halving the wave that goes to motor (it's an AC motor); when the current for the motor passes through the diode, the motor receives half AC wave and the fan is low. When the diode is out of the circuit, the fan runs at full speed.

Comment: Please note that the safety of this device relies on the thermostat on the heating element, because the motor and the heater are powered in parallel, so, if the motor fails, or stalls, the heater will keep powered. It is an AC motor [link for the picture of the motor](https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1152541912). The most common failure of this device is the breakup of the copper wires inside the power cable. The next common failure is the breakup of NiChrome wires in the [heating element](https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-1086860916). Failure of the motor is quite unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505868/poko-td-169c-hair-dryer-circuit-diagram) question you can see the typical schematic of a two-speed inexpensive hair dryer.

[image]

The heater forms a voltage divider to feed the low voltage DC motor (via a bridge rectifier), and you can switch an additional rectifier in series for 'low'. The fuse (FU = 熔断器) and thermostat (ST = 恆溫器) are for obvious safety reasons. If the air flow is obstructed for any reason or the fan fails the heater temperature will rapidly increase so some form of safety cutoff is required. The "FU" is likely a one-time thermal fuse that acts as a backup bricking the appliance if it seriously overheats, and the "ST" is a thermostat that closes once the dryer cools down a bit.

If you want to see a higher end dryer, have a look at tear-down videos of the Dyson hair dryer. It costs about $500 CAD ($400 USD) and uses a high speed (110,000 RPM so the racket is mostly ultrasonic) BLDC motor.

Comment: I like the differential AND gate driving it all... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting adding a half wave rectifier to reduce the speed on the "Low" setting ? I tried putting it in series with the bridge and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: It needs to go on the mains side in series with the whole mess as shown on the schematic at the switch position marked '冷'. After the bridge it will do nothing much. It cuts the heater power by 50% and reduces the motor speed.